# Oracle 11g SELF member procedure not working

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have the following:

```
create type customer as object (
id number, name varchar2(10), points number,
member procedure add_points(num_points number)
) not final;
/

create type body customer as
member procedure add_points(num_points number) is 
begin
   points := points + num_points;
   commit;
end add_points;
end;
/

create table customer_table of customer;
/

insert into customer_table values (customer(123,'joe',10));
/
```

i then do this is an anonymous block:

```
declare
cust customer;
begin
select treat(value(c) as customer) into cust from customer_table c where id=123;
c.add_points(100);
end;
```

but nothing happens - the points value remains at 10.

What have i missed? If i make my member procedure an `update...set...commit` and pass in the points and a given id, it works.

Thanks.

Comment: I know from dealing with one of your previous questions that you are on a training course of some sort.  Unfortunately they do seem to be training you in some rather arcane and pointless features of Oracle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PL/SQL you posted is invalid.  I guess you meant to post this:

```
declare
  cust customer;
begin
  select treat(value(c) as customer) into cust from customer_table c where id=123;
  cust.add_points(100);
end;
```

i.e. "cust" not "c" on line 5?

If so, all you have done there is updated the value of points *in the variable cust*, not in the table.  You can see that like this:

```
declare
  cust customer;
begin
  select treat(value(c) as customer) into cust from customer_table c where id=123;
  cust.add_points(100);
  dbms_output.put_line(cust.points);
end;
```

Output:

```
110
```

To update the data in the table does indeed require an UPDATE statement.